# How do I programmatically determine the CCSID of a file in the IFS?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, ibm-ifs

I have many files in the IFS with a wide variety of CCSIDs (0, 37, 819, 1200, 1252, etc.) and I've been tasked with writing a simple RPGLE [1] program that will allow a user to view the contents of any of these files.

Our system (V6R1) CCSID (DSPSYSVAL QCCSID) is 65535 [2] and our jobs have a default CCSID of 37 which means when I try to display CCSID 819 (ASCII) for example, I see garbage – symbols, random colors, etc.

I am familiar with converting data from one CCSID to another via the [QtqIconvOpen](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/QTQICONV.htm) API so if I know a file has a CCSID that differs from our default CCSID, I can convert it. I wrote code years ago to do that and it works fine.

My problem is finding out the CCSID of the IFS file programmatically.  After Googling the only relevant information I found was here on Stackoverflow from JamesA ([How to determine the CCSID used in CPYFRMIMPF command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982810/how-to-determine-the-ccsid-used-in-cpyfrmimpf-command)) who points out that you can execute “ls -S” in a QSHELL to get a listing of files showing their CCSID and filename.

So theoretically I could execute `ls -S filename`, parse the output to get the CCSID and then use that CCSID to perform a conversion of the data if necessary.  That's an ugly hack though and I'd much prefer to use an IBM API if possible.

Does anyone know of such an API or a more elegant hack than parsing a listing from `ls -S filename`?

[1] I use the C API's `open()`, `read()` and `close()` to do the actual reading of data.

[2] I know 65535 is a poor choice but there's nothing I can do about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the [`Qp0lGetAttr()` "Get Attributes" API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/qgetattr.htm) will let you specify a set of attributes to retrieve for a particular file, including one called `QP0L_ATTR_CCSID`.

[Here's an example of this API in use from RPG.](http://www.think400.dk/apier_7.htm#eks0006)  The example including the GetAttr call is in a [ZIP file linked from that page](http://www.think400.dk/files/CBX1270.zip).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [stat()](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/stat.htm) function from the integrated file system APIs.

The prototype definition looks like this:

```
D stat            PR            10I 0 ExtProc('stat')                   
D   path                          *   Value Options(*string)            
D   buf                               Likeds(statDS)
```

Then you also need the stat data structure:

```
 D statDS          DS                  Qualified Template
 D  st_mode                      10U 0
 D  st_ino                       10U 0
 D  st_nlink                      5U 0
 D  st_reserved2                  5U 0
 D  st_uid                       10U 0
 D  st_gid                       10U 0
 D  st_size                      10I 0
 D  st_atime                     10I 0
 D  st_mtime                     10I 0
 D  st_ctime                     10I 0
 D  st_dev                       10U 0
 D  st_blksize                   10U 0
 D  st_allocsize                 10U 0
 D  st_objtype                   11A
 D  st_reserved3                  1A
 D  st_codepage                   5U 0
 D  st_ccsid                      5U 0
 D  st_rdev                      10U 0
 D  st_nlink32                   10U 0
 D  st_rdev64                    20U 0
 D  st_dev64                     20U 0
 D  st_reserved1                 36A
 D  st_ino_gen_id                10U 0
```

using it is pretty easy

```
 D fileStats       DS                  Likeds(statDS)

  /free
     if stat('/path/to/file': fileStats) < 0;
        // error handling
     endif;

     // ccsid now in fileStats.st_ccsid
  /end-free
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason not to use DSPF for this?  IBM's utility does a great job; not sure what eles you might need.

Comment: He asked how do do it "programmatically".  Using DSPF isn't all that program friendly.

Comment: Sorry.  I assumed one would know how to use QCMDEXC.  Perhaps not.

Comment: Often, when someone says 'programmatically' they mean they want to do something with the information inside a program.  DSPF won't allow for that.

Comment: First off, I asked if it was a fit... didn't say it was.  Secondly, I was going by original spec (and this is my last reply to this; it's all moot.)  "and I've been tasked with writing a simple RPGLE [1] program that will allow a user to view the contents of any of these files."

Comment: QCMDEXC just runs a command ... it doesn't return any information. Not very useful unless you just want to display the contents of a file. Plus, DSPF is only interactive, so it's not going to help much if the job is running in batch.